# User input filename to specific directory

Tags: c++

how do i let the user name the file, but have it placed in a specific directory?

```
int main(){

  std::cout << "enter filename" << std::endl;
  std::string filename;
  std::cin >> filename;

    std::ofstream file (filename, std::ios::app);
```

Say i wanted to place their named file inside F:\Programming\Visual Studio\C++ Programming\C++\ofstream_and_ifstream, what would be the appropriate way for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "enter filename" << std::endl;
    std::string filename;
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::string path("F:\\Programming\\Visual Studio\\C++ Programming\\C++\\ofstream_and_ifstream\\");

    std::ofstream file (path + filename, std::ios::app);
}
```

After the filename is entered, you need to check if it is a valid filename, so he does not enter any directory name and so on